# Joining multiple dataframes on a common column

Tags: python, pandas, outer-join

I have multiple dataframes (total of 6). I have a common column in all the dataframes. Is there a way to join all the columns in all the dataframe on the common column? I know merge command, but it seems to work on only 2 dataframes at a time. Is there a way we can write a single statement to perform this? I do not want any data loss so I believe outer join is the best.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`set_index` and use `pd.concat`:

```
pd.concat([i.set_index('A') for i in [df1,df2,df3]],axis=1, join='outer')
```

Comment: Thank you! Just what I was looking for!